# Express application automatic deploy configuration

Tags: node.js, express, deployment

Let's suppose I have Express application and install it such way:

1. Clone from git sources of the application
2. run `npm install`
3. Edit app's configuration in `/config`

What if I want automatically perform some actions on deploy, like default user creation, fill some collections by start data, etc. How can I do that on the most generic way?

And how can I do it without business logics duplication in a kind of `deploy.js` to be run, if the app is a REST API?

Answer (score 1):

You can initially run a a file like `node setup.js`.

Once that is complete run the express.js application like so: `node app.js`.

The `setup.js` would initialize pre-deploy configurations.

Does that make sense?

Comment: That's a nice answer, thank you. Can you give an advice how to apply your solution in such case:

I have mocha tests, and running the app such way 


```beforeEach(function () {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve('../app.js')];
        app = require('../app.js');                    
        request = require('supertest').agent(server = app.listen());```

How can I run ```setup.js``` before ```app=...```?